# Insert iterated keys inside another object in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an object that receives coordinates values ​​like this

```
Object{
[key]:[value],
[key]:[value],
}
```

Each key is a coordinate x,y and each value is a true boolean. I generate the coordinates through a program that receives an array with values ​​0 for true and 1 for false, a width and a height.

I want to output each key as a coordinate x,y inside that object in this way:

```
Object{
[gridCoords([0, 0, 0, 0,
             1, 1, 0, 1,
             0, 0, 0, 0,
             0, 0, 0, 0],
             4,
             4)]:true,
}
```

So, my function is something like this:

```
function gridCoords(data, height, width)  {
  var obj = [];
  for (let row = 0; row < height; row++) {
    for (let col = 0; col < width; col++) {
      let key=`${row * 16},${col * 16}`
      let value= (data[row * height + col] === 1 ? true: false )
      if (value){
        obj.push(key)
      }
    }
  }
  return obj
}
```

But i received this:

```
{
16,0,16,16,16,48,32,16,32,32: true
}
```

Instead of:

```
{
16,0: true,
16,16: true,
16,48: true,
32,16: true,
32,32: true
}
```

What I can do?

Answer (score 2):

I think you want an object not an array here:

```
function gridCoords(data, height, width)  {
  var obj = {};
  for (let row = 0; row < height; row++) {
    for (let col = 0; col < width; col++) {
      let key=`${row * 16},${col * 16}`
      let value= (data[row * height + col] === 1 ? true: false )
      if (value){
        obj[key] = value
      }
    }
  }
  return Object.keys(obj)
}
```

Comment: You are right!!! But that returns me [key]:[value] and i want only the keys, because the [value] is already in the main object. Will be possible?

Comment: You can return the object with only the keys by calling `Object.keys`

Comment: Thanks. The thing is that still output me this {
16,0,16,16,16,48,32,16,32,32: true} in the object where i call the function.

Comment: Don't call Object.keys on the return value and don't wrap the function call in another object

Comment: Just call it like so `gridCoords([0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], 4,4)`